# Theano - Compute element wise sum of list of theano matrix

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, theano

I have a list of theano matrices(using in a neural network implementation). I need to perform element wise sum on the corresponding elements.

Eg Input :`x1 = [<TensorType(float64, matrix)>, <TensorType(float64, matrix)> , <TensorType(float64, matrix)>]`

```
Output : <TensorType(float64, matrix)> -> which is the element wise sum of the 3 matrices.
```

Looked at a few posts but unable to figure out how to proceed. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use *scan* function in theano, and you have to make sure that each matrix in the list has the same shape.